# How to remove Remote Address from response header in mvc website?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8, iis-10

[How to remove Remote Address from response header in MVC website?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIyD5.png)

After hosting on server it shows server IP address, and also am using IIS 10

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/24885/how-to-remove-iis-asp-net-response-headers

Comment: This link should help you: [https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/ba-p/369710](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/ba-p/369710).